# How do I let the user draw (like MS Paint) a picture in the given space (50x50) and saving that picture as a texture2D? XNA

Tags: xna, drawing, texture2d

I was thinking of making a windows form with a 50x50 space somewhere on it (bitmap?) and having the user draw (like MS Paint) inside the square. When the user is done, the picture can be saved by clicking on the "save" button and it will be updated in Game1 (for collision purposes of my game). I've seen some tutorials on here on how to draw on screen like MS Paint, but I can't seem to figure out how to SAVE that picture as a Texture2D/Rectangle. And how do I get a bitmap onto a windows form?

Answer (score 0):

To save a bitmap as a png:

```
private void SaveBmpAsPNG(Bitmap bm)
{
    bm.Save(@"c:\button.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

To write a texture2d to a file:

```
using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite("picture.png"))
{
    texture.SaveAsPng(stream, texture.Width, texture.Height);
}
```

To read a .png into a texture2d:

```
using(Stream stream = File.OpenRead("picture.png"))
{
   texture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, stream);
}
```